# Tools for automatically simplifying regexes

Tags: ruby, regex, code-analysis

I'm trying to squash warnings in an open source project, and

```
/[\.\,\;\:\(\)\[\]\{\}\<\>\"\'\`\~\/\|\?\!\&\@\#\s\x00-\x1f\x7f]+/
```

is giving me

```
(irb):1: warning: character class has duplicated range
```

Are there any tools that automatically point out which parts of the regexp causes the overlap?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any tool, but I've spotted the overlap: `\s` contains `\t`, `\f`, `\n` and `\r`, so that overlaps with the `\x00-\x1f` part.

So, unless there's a way to get Ruby itself to tell you that it found a "problem", you can write this regex as (removing all those unnecessary backslashes along the way):

```
/[.,;:()\[\]{}<>"'`~\/|?!&@# \x00-\x1f\x7f]+/
```

Comment: Extending the range to `\x00-\x20` is another option to include `space`.

Answer (score 3):

If you ever reach that point of desperation, I guess you could put outputting some debug info in Ruby source and rebuild. :) I believe this is the place where the warning is thrown:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/regparse.c#L1787